# Oracle APEX: Call stored procedure from javascript

Tags: javascript, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-apex

I need some help with oracle apex. The thing which I want to do is the following:
I have table with some data about people. So each row describes exactly one human. And I want to show some more information about certain human. For example, list of shops he or she has visited. Such data provided by other tables.

I see it in this way: right click on table with people on certain row -> select option (what kind of info to show) -> execute stored procedure and show new page with data table (e.g. list of shops). But how can I implement it?

I've already found [this plugin](http://apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/dynamic-action-plugin/contextrightclick-menu_193.html). Now I can execute some JavaScript function after right-click. But how can I execute stored procedure and show new page?

I'm new in apex, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible. First of all, assume that each row contains unique identifier ID. You have to add hidden item to the page which would contain additional info about certain row. Let's name it P1_ID. Then add the following JavaScript code to page which contains initial data (in example from question, page with table with information about people):

```
function TestFunction(action, el, pos) {
 var id = $(el).children('td[headers="ID"]').text();
 var href = 'f?p={APPLICATION ID}:{PAGE_NUMBER}:&SESSION.::::P2_ID:'+id;            
 window.location = href
}
```

Function name should match name in plugin settings. Example: [link](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=1983:17)

Replace APPLICATION_ID and PAGE_NUMBER with actual values according to application. PAGE_NUMBER is the page number which contains additional info about row.

Then you can add some reports to the page with additional info and use ID parameter to select information about certain row.

The only problem is that plugin mentioned in question stop working after table refreshing. For example, if we filter data in table then no menu on right click will be shown. I don't know how to fix it for now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reinvent the wheel. You're new to apex. Have you taken a good look at [the documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/documentation/index.html)?
Start out where everyone else has to start: at the beginning. Report + form. Column links.
There is ample help available to someone new to apex.

- [The 2-day developer guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35122/toc.htm), running you through some of the
  basics of apex and a good familiarization.
- Get a workspace at [apex.oracle.com](http://apex.oracle.com)
- Each workspace starts with the sample database application, based on
  products and customers. You can view and edit this application and
  thus you can glean plenty of information from it.
- Furthermore, there are the packaged applications, many of which offer
  good basic solutions to common situations. Again, you can glean a lot
  of information on them, and they are even editable after you unlocked
  them.

After you are familiar with the basics, you can look further ahead. What you are asking is simply too much for someone new to the matter. You even want to implement a jQuery plugin straight away. You're talking ajax. It's great if you know those subjects and they'll be of plenty of value to you, but it just seems you don't even know how to present and fetch your data.
A good start would be to make a report and a form. In the form you can then add some classic (or an interactive) report(s) to represent associated data.

Comment: I don't think I'm completely new to apex. I know basic principles and want to find out how to solve my problem. How documentation can help me? Does it contains answers for all questions? I don't think so. Of course, I tried to find answer but have found nothing. And I decided to ask a question. But instead of answer, I've got weird answer. Have you got something according to my question?

Comment: @pfedotovsky Yes, my answer contains something useful . I don't see how it doesn't. I'm not blaming you for being new - something which you yourself have indicated. In that context I am wondering why you would go the convoluted way and want a right-click context menu instead of the usual, standard, column-link way. For all I know, when reading your question, you seem to think that is the way to "link" pages together. And why would you diss documentation? The sources I mention contain a lot of useful information for anyone setting out.

Comment: @pfedotovsky Furthermore, if you knew all this, all you had to was to outline it in your question. I just couldn't make it up from it. There are so few people asking questions here, and usually those people are beginners. So again, for all I know, you're new and looking for a complex way to solve a simple issue. You wouldn't have had to slam my answer for being weird if I would've been able to discern this. And an example on apex.oracle.com is always great to help others understand your issue.